# How to create a inter process communication between javascript process and python process running on same hardware machine

Tags: javascript, node.js, python-3.x, ipc

How to implement Inter-Process Communication between javascript process and the python process running on nodejs on the same hardware.

I am having a hardware device which runs on nodejs. I have to integrate a python code with this hardware device which receives data from javascript process at every 10 seconds and performs machine learning with the received data.
How to implement IPC between them.

Comment: Try spawning a child process (python process) in node, make use of stdout and stdin for the data communications

Comment: Spawning child process is not allowed, as then we need to spawn the python process every 10 seconds. I want both processes to run once. Spawning once is allowed, but again and again, is not allowed.

Comment: Here is a sample article for head start , https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2015/08/21/python-nodejs-comm/

Comment: This article I have already looked at. But not suited for my requirements.

Comment: you will be pushing the node js data only every 10 sec, u can use the same instance of the process to keep the stdout , would this approach suffice ?

Comment: If it runs in nodejs you can generate an endpoint for communications. https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-rest

Comment: Nivnedha, Even, in that case, the python process will be called by creating a new child process everytime.

Comment: Sam, if possible can you give sample code for that as I am not getting that.